# Doctrine2 Symfony2 Custom function parser

Tags: mysql, sql, function, symfony, doctrine-orm

i try to add my custom sql function.

my function is like this :

```
DISTANCE( 15.154454, 5.121444, -15.321111, 15.12111)
```

I add this parser for parse it :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class Distance extends \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode
{
    public $lat_a = null;
    public $lat_b = null;
    public $lon_a = null;
    public $lon_b = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->lat_a = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->lon_a = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->lat_b = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->lon_b = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'DISTANCE(' .
        $this->lat_a->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ', ' .
        $this->lon_a->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ', ' .
        $this->lat_b->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ', ' .
        $this->lon_b->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
        ')';
    }
}
```

It's ok, this work fine but when i use negative var like "-15.321111", i get an error 500...
With positive var, all it's ok.

Anyone can help me for parse negative var ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
{
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
    $this->lat_a = $parser->ArithmeticExpression();
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
    $this->lon_a = $parser->ArithmeticExpression();
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
    $this->lat_b = $parser->ArithmeticExpression();
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
    $this->lon_b = $parser->ArithmeticExpression();
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
}

public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
{
    return 'DISTANCE(' .
    $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticExpression($this->lat_a) . ', ' .
    $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticExpression($this->lon_a) . ', ' .
    $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticExpression($this->lat_b) . ', ' .
    $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticExpression($this->lon_b) .
    ')';
}
```

Comment: It's ok thx for help.
I just use ArithmeticExpression in parse and all work ok.